# select new added ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have Main and Detail forms. The Main form has ListView1. I would like to select **new added** ListViewItem in ListView1 when user click Save button in Detail form. I have problem only when I'm adding new item. When I modify and save existing item according item is selected after save command. I will appreciate for sample.

Comment: Some example code would be beneficial for us to help you identify where your problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me if I add it to the Save button handler in the second form:

```
    With Form1.ListView1
        .Items.Add("item from form2")

        For i As Integer = 1 To .Items.Count
            .Items(i - 1).Selected = (i = .Items.Count)
        Next
    End With
```